# How to submit a suspend bug for 17.10

Tags: suspend, power-management, 17.10

Hello I'm trying out Ubuntu 17.10 beta. What is the right way to submit a suspend bug? Is there a specific package?

The issue is:

1. New install of 17.10 beta 2 on XPS 13 9350
2. Select top right menu, hold alt, select suspend button

I expect the laptop to suspend. Instead the screen goes blank. The laptop remained on (power button is light, fans are on). The laptop is unresponsive until hard reboot (holding down power button).

I have read the submitting a bug wiki but I do not see how to submit a bug related to suspend as I am unsure what package it would be part of.

Comment: When in doubt, search for similar bug reports - https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/?advanced=1 search "suspend", most appear to be against the kernel.

Answer (score 0):

I'd report this bug for the Linux package.

Comment: Thanks, based on this and bodhi's comment I reported it under linux using `ubuntu-bug linux`. [Bug report](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/1720557)